# Find $a \in \{0, ..., 9\}$ so that period of a sequence is the longest

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am give a sequence defined by the relation

$s_{n + 3} = s_{n + 1} + as_{n}$

and need to determine, for which value of $a \in \{0, ... , 9\}$ the period of a sequence in the field $\mathbb{F}_{31}$ is the longest.

From the relation I derived a characteristic polynomial $\varphi(z) = z^3 - z - a$. Since the degree of the polynomial is 3, it's order (and the period of a sequence) must divide $31^3 - 1$. Trying all of divisors by hand seems not right.

Are there any other methods or observations that could be made to simplify the task?

Comment: The polynomial you should consider is actually $z^3-z-a$ not $z^2-z-a$. You missed the jump between $s_{n+1}$ and $s_{n+3}$ (or is this a typo ?)

Comment: Oh, it's actually my mistake, thanks for pointing that out. I will edit the post

Comment: While $N=31^3-1$ has a lot of divisors, it has only four prime divisors : $2,3,5$ and $331$ (in fact $N=2 \times 3^2 \times 5 \times 331$ ). So, you only need to check the four divisors $\frac{N}{p}$ for $p=2,3,5$ or $331$.

Comment: Why does the order necessarily one of the $\frac{N}{p}?$

Comment: It is not necessarily one of the $\frac{N}{p}$, but either it is maximal (equal to $N$), or it divides one of the $\frac{N}{p}$.

Comment: But how does it help me to find the period of the sequence? If, suppose, order divides $\frac{N}{331}$, I still don't know the order exactly

Comment: What happens here is that for $a=3$, the order is exactly $N$, and for other $a$, the order divides $31^2-1$.